# QGIS-Custom functions not showing in Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-custom-function

I'm using Essen and trying to follow Anita Graser's wonderful tutorial [Illuminated contours](https://anitagraser.com/2015/05/24/how-to-create-illuminated-contours-tanaka-style/).  I've created the `azimuth` function and loaded it but there is nothing showing in the expression tab - not even Custom with the default func!  The expression exists as `azimuth.py` in C`:\Users\Max\.qgis2\python\expressions` with associated `.pyc` file.  Restarting QGIS doesn't make any difference

[image]

[image]

Comment: I take it you remembered to hit the 'Load' button?  I also found some older scripts caused problems when I tried to reallocate them to a new group - I got no syntax errors, but correcting indentation manually from using TAB to 4 spaces fixed this. This might be worth checking, especially if you pasted the code in? (I see you're using 2 spaces for indent). The fold marker (the minus sign after the line number) looks ok though...

Comment: @StevenKay Thanks Steven for the first time I have an error on the code and it is to do with indentation.  I wasn't aware of this and yes I had pasted the code in..  Just to confirm, there should always be 4 spaces at the beginning of a line - I notice that the function editor does some automatic indentation?

Comment: @Max - I would strongly suggest using a text editor to fix your indentation and then paste it into the expression window. A number of these editors will highlight whether your indentation is wrong. There are many text editors out there, for example, I love using [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) ;)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks I will do - really appreciate all the assistance

Comment: @Max Did you ever solve this? I experience the same. My custom functions do not load when qgis starts so I have to enter the function editor tab and press "load" before the custom functions show up in the expression editor tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Do not** call the function `azimuth` as there is already an existing *Math* function called this.

Instead give it another name like `azi()`:

[image: Example script]

And now you should be able to call it:

[image: Custom expression]

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the math function.  However it still isn't showing in the expressions tab once created and loaded.  As I said previously there is no heading called "Custom" at all so for the next step in the tutorial I'm a bit stuffed (this is my first time using expressions and functions in QGIS...maybe my last if I can't finish this tutorial!)

Comment: @Max - What QGIS version are you using? Have you considered upgrading to the more latest version? I tested this on QGIS 2.14.3-Essen and it loaded fine.

Comment: I've tried it on 2.14.8 Essen and 2.16.3.I think I will uninstall and reinstall - I use OSGeo for installation and I wonder if perhaps something has screwed up somewhere?

Comment: @Max - Could be. Before reinstalling, try deleting the `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/python/expressions` folder (or back up any scripts that you used).

Comment: Have deleted it (tried that before and reloading but to no avail)  currently reinstalling - will get back to you...thanks

Comment: @Max - Hopefully it will work. Otherwise, maybe you can [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/215278/edit) your question to include the exact code you used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47374/discussion-between-max-and-joseph).